# Web app using java and angularjs

Tags: java, ajax, angularjs, jdbc, dto

i'm trying to create simple market web application. I want to add a sign-in functionality to add users in my db, but i can't understand, how can i "call" my registration method (from java) in js script. Currently, the only thing that my web-app actually does is show records(which i added manually) from users-table.

Here is my db-manager:

```
`public class DatabaseManager {
    public static String host = "localhost";
    public static String port = "5432";
    public static String dbname = "market";
    public static String user = "postgres";
    public static String pass = "123456";

    public static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://"+host+":"+port+"/"+dbname+"?user="+user+"&password="+pass;

   static {
       try {
           DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can not connect to the database:\n"+e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection connection) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}`
```

Auth - dto:

```
public class Auth {

public static class RegisterReq {
    public String name;
    public String lastname;
    public String login;
    public String pass;
    public int age;
    public String gender;

    public RegisterReq(String name, String lastname, String login, String pass, int age, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.login = login;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}

public static class RegisterResp {

    public boolean status;

    public RegisterResp(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}


public static class LoginReq {
    public String login;
    public String pass;


    public LoginReq(String login, String pass) {
        this.login = login;
        this.pass = pass;
    }
}

public static class LoginResp {

    public boolean status;

    public LoginResp(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

}

Auth-class with sign-up method:
`

```
import static dto.Auth.*;
@Path("/auth")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Auth {

    @POST
    @Path("/register")
    public RegisterResp register(RegisterReq req) {

        boolean result = false;

        //sql
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DatabaseManager.getConnection();

            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

            String checkSql = "select e_mail from users";

            ResultSet resultSet=stmt.executeQuery(checkSql);

            while (resultSet.next()) {
               if(req.login.equals(resultSet.getString(1))) return new RegisterResp(result);
            }

            //unsafe query
            String sql = "INSERT INTO users" +
                    " (u_name, u_lastname, e_mail, password, age, gender, reg_date)" +
                    " VALUES (" +
                    req.name  + ","+
                    req.lastname  + ","+
                    req.login  + ","+
                    req.pass  + "," +
                    req.age  + ","+
                    req.gender + ","+
                    new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime())  + ")";

            result = stmt.execute(sql);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) DatabaseManager.closeConnection(connection);
        }

        return new RegisterResp(result);
    }`
```

Main page HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Market start page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/app.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="UserController">

<div style="background: #8fb9ee" class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Market homepage</h1>
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
    <p align="center">
        <a href="#/register" style="background: sandybrown" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  role="button">Register</a>
        <a href="#/login" style="background: #606cf4" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  role="button">Log in</a>
    </p>
</div>
<hr>

<div >
    <ul>
        <p style="font-size: xx-large" >Total user count: {{users.length}}   </p>

        <table class="TableStyle">
            <tr  class="RowHeaderStyle">
                <th >Firstname</th>
                <th >Lastname</th>
                <th >E-mail</th>
                <th >Age</th>
                <th >Gender</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users" class="RowStyle">
                <td >{{user.name}}</td>
                <td >{{user.lastname}}</td>
                <td >{{user.e_mail}}</td>
                <td >{{user.age}}</td>
                <td >{{user.gender}}</td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </ul>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value"> admin ?

<div ng-if="value">Admin</div>
<div ng-if="!value">User</div>

<div ng-view></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./resources/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Register HTML-file:

```
    <h2>Register</h2>
<div ng-controller="RegisterController"  align="center" class="container-fluid">

        <table >

                <tr>

                    <td>First name</td>
                    <td><input  type="text" ng-model="fname"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>


                <td>Last name</td>
                <td><input  type="text" ng-model="lname"></td>

            </tr>

                <tr>


                    <td>E-mail</td>
                    <td><input  type="text" ng-model="uemail"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>


                    <td>Confirm Password</td>
                    <td><input  type="text" ng-model="upass"></td>

                </tr>


                <tr>


                    <td>Gender</td>
                    <td>

                     <select  ng-model="ugend" >
                        <option>male</option>
                        <option>female</option>
                     </select>

                     </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>


                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="uage"></td>

                </tr>


            </table>

    <button  role="button" ng-click="AddUser()"> Confirm </button>


</div>
```

And app JS file with my silly tries to do something:

```
`angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: './resources/partials/login.html',
            controller: 'RegisterController'
        }).
        when('/register', {
            templateUrl: './resources/partials/register.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}])
.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {

    var User = $resource('/r/users');

    var users = User.query(function() {
        $scope.users = users;
    });

}])
.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {



}])

.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', '$resource',"$http", function($scope,$http, $resource) {

        //here should be something smart
        $scope.AddUser =  function() {


        };

}]);`
```

I'm working in Intellij, and this is my first try to do something, so don't stone me =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly, your RegisterController should look like this:

```
.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {

    var auth = $resource('/auth/:action', null, {
        login: {
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
                action: 'login'
            },
        },
        register: {
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
                action: 'register'
            }
        }
    });


    $scope.AddUser =  function() {

        // your data consumed from UI
        var data = {
            name: $scope.name
            lastname: $scope.lastname,
            login: $scope.login,
            pass: $scope.pass,
            age: $scope.age,
            gender: $scope.gender
        }; 

        auth.register(null, data, function(resp) {
            // your callback when response is received
            // resp variable contains response data sent from server
            if (resp.status) {
                // registered successfully
            } else {
                // some error occurred
            }
        });
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i was lookin for.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correcty. One way to go about that is to create an angular service to perform the ajax post ill paste an example from a current spring-boot angular app im developping. im using es6 but the conecpt is the same

So here is a snippet of the service

```
class UserService
{
  constructor($http)
  {
    HTTP.set(this, $http);
  }


//  getGroups(groupId){
//    return HTTP.get(this).get(`/api/v1/group/group/?id=${groupId}`).then(result => result.data.objects );
//  }
//  
//  createUserInGroup(groupId,user){
//    return HTTP.get(this).post(`/api/v1/group/user/${groupId}`,user);
//  }
  updateUser(userId,user){
      return HTTP.get(this).put(`/api/v1/user/${userId}`, user);
  }
```

You can tell im injecting the $http angular object to be able to perform the request, you'll have to do the same thing if you decide to go with making a service

In The controller, Im injecting the service

```
class NewGroupController{
  constructor($timeout,$modalInstance, groupSvc,currentGroup){
    GROUP_SERVICE.set(this, groupSvc);
    MODAL_INSTANCE.set(this,$modalInstance);
    TIMEOUT.set(this, $timeout);
    CURRENT_GROUP.set(this,currentGroup);
```

With the Group Service in i can call the method and thats it.

Hope it helps